I Need Help With My Tanky Monk
I'm about to start playing a campaign in my school's D&D club, and we need a tank. I've already made my Monk for filling this role: (https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/118201913) but I need advice on how to make it a more efficient tank. I am only in high school, so if I did something wrong with equipment or any such things, let me know. If you can't access the link (this is my first time posting on this website and my first time having a public character) let me know and I'll spend a couple days troubleshooting. I'm trying to have a character that will withstand attacks based on AC and maybe dodging (distracting the enemies rather than absorbing damage), not necessarily hit points, and I don't really need it to truly tank until a little later, around maybe 5th level. We just need a tank at some point. I'm playing on the most recent version on D&D Beyond, which I assume would be the 2024 version or 5e, however I have no idea if I'm right.
P.S. -Some people would accuse me of cheating with the ability scores, but just to clear things up, I used manual rolled (which is suspicious in itself to some) and Aarakocras have a natural +2 Dex and +1 Wis.

Hey! Welcome to the site. Before we go forward, can you let us know whether this is the 2014 or 2024 edition of D&D you're using?

I've added the 5e-2014 tag based on the description of your character's Martial Arts feature. The 2024 version has higher damage and allows Dexterity to be used for setting the DC of grapple checks. If this is incorrect, please revise.

Can you clarify a bit on your stated goal of 'make it a more efficient tank'? As written, this goal is a bit nebulous as you've not stated when you want to achieve it and how. For example, a 1st level Monk may not really be able to be especially 'tanky' if the definition is to be able to draw attacks to them and lock enemies down. However, at 5th level a Monk might have a few more options to achieve those goals (if those are your goals). Can you expand your definition of 'tanky' and give us a rough idea to what level you expect the game to go?

Does this answer your question: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/63606/31402

I think so, thank you Pyrotechnical

This question is similar to: How do I make a tanky Monk?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
