# Mage Armor + Unarmored Defense?

Tags: dnd-5e, armor-class

Playing a barbarian, and thought the Magic Initiate feat would be a good way to grab some range cantrips and a single-use utility spell. Originally thought of going with warlock, but DM suggested I go wizard or sorcerer and grab Mage Armor so I could be a naked man with an AC of 18 (w/ 2h) or 20 (w/shield) at level one. 
UD says that as long as I'm not wearing armor, my AC is base (10) +con+dex. Mage armor ups the base to 13.
Would I still retain the dex & con bonuses, from unarmored defense?

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46569/how-does-mage-armor-interact-with-unarmored-defense

Comment: Thank you all, very much. I'm not sure why I couldn't find the other posts about this, but it coincides with my original understanding of the calculations, (before hearing the DM interpretation.)

Comment: That’s ok! Asking and then being directed to an already-asked question is one of the ways of getting answers here. As a bonus, your question’s wording gives another way to Google for it, so you’ve helped future searchers find the answer too. Thanks for the contribution!