# How does the Swashbuckler's Suave Defense feature work with the Robe of the Archmagi?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, armor-class, traits

If I were to give Suave Defense trait to a player and if they have the Robe of the Archmagi, how would it work?

[Suave Defense](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/swashbuckler) states:

> While the swashbuckler is wearing light or no armor and wielding no shield, its AC includes its Charisma modifier.

[Robe of the Archmagi](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/robe-of-the-archmagi) states:

> [...] If you aren't wearing armor, your base Armor Class is 15 + your Dexterity modifier.

So would the player have a Armor Class of 15 + Dexterity modifier + Charisma modifier?

Would giving a player Suave Defense that has the Robe of the Archmagi be too strong?

Comment: Are you the DM in this case?

Comment: And how would a player get Suave Defense?

Comment: What do you mean by "giving a player Suave Defense"? Do you mean giving them a new class feature in homebrew?

Comment: I think if you remove the question at the end, we can answer that. The  question at the end is definitely Primarily Opinion Based, though.

Comment: You could probably pare this down even further and just ask about giving the Suave Defense feature to a PC.

Comment: What are the criteria for determining if it's too strong or not?

Comment: @Upper_Case Balance can usually be estimated by comparing against other official classes.

Comment: @MikeQ Right, but the "too strong" question has been identified as problematic, so I'm trying to nudge the question into being more specific and answerable, rather than staying on hold until it gets closed.

Comment: Related: [How does Mage Armor interact with Unarmored Defense?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/46593/48793)

Comment: I agree that we can't answer whether something "is too strong", we are sorely lacking in context. First of all, too strong compared to what? Compared to the enemies that the PC will face? Compared to his party members? If so, how strong are the enemies and party members and are they similarly equipped with legendary items and extra features? Moreover, what's the charisma of the PC? Etc.

Comment: Looks like you've got several questions here. On StackExchange, we have a pretty strict one-question-per-post policy. I would start with clarifying - either by editing this question, or with help by asking another one - what you mean by "give a PC Suave Defense", since that would have to be homebrew. Once you've nailed that down, you can move on to "would that stack with Robe of the Archmagi?" and from there to "would giving a PC both be too much?" (with the necessary info to make that answerable.)

Answer (score 1):

## As written I would say that you are correct in it giving the player an AC of 15 + DEX + CHA.

My reason for saying this is that while two features that define your AC calculation don't stack (such as Mage Armor and Unarmored Defense) however you don't have that here. What you have is the robes which define your base AC and the feature which adds a modifier (in this case your CHA mod) to it. Those sorts of features DO stack as I recall. There's also the word "includes" which leads me to believe that this is the case.

I can't really answer your other part of the question, "Would [it] be too strong?" as that varies based on a number of factors, including but not necessarily limited to: The other players in the party, the types of monsters you'll be fighting, and the overall power level of the story in general.